# Antlr3 - HIDDEN token in the parser

Tags: parsing, antlr, token, lexer, channel

Can you use a token defined in the lexer in a hidden channel in a single rule of the parser as if it were a normal token?
The generated code is Java...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you construct a CommonTokenStream, you tell it what channel to use. Tokens on other channels will not be visible to the parser.

Comment: I refer to this http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557063. But not being an expert in ANTLR not understand how to use these methods.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a hidden token in the Parser.

We do this all the time.  The only problem is that you need to know when to look for it.

Antlr has a few pieces of terminology that it uses.

A `Hidden` token just travels on a separate stream.  The user can always check for hidden tokens by calling `getHiddenAfter` or `getHiddenBefore` on a currently matched token.

*Note:* There may be more than one token hidden, before or after, a matched token so you should iterate through them.

A `Discarded` token is actually removed when you tell the lexer to discard it.  It will never be seen by you again.